# How to migrate from one mysql table to another similar table containing autoincremented column

Tags: mysql, production

I have one MySql production table which contains an auto-increment column. As the table is in production, user data is kept inserting into the table and id got generated accordingly. How can I migrate the existing table to another similar one without conflict in ids of records that inserted during the migration time?

Answer (score 0):

assuming  your production table contain id_col autoincrement and col1,col2 
and assuming that your similar table (my_dest_table ) contains  a specific autoincrement column id_dest autoincrement 
(id_dest, col1, col2)
   you could try using  insert/select  selecting   the columns but not the one with the  id

```
        insert into my_dest_table ( colA, colB )
        select  col1, col2 
        from my_production_table
```

but if you want  store also the production id then you could add this in a proper column

```
        insert into my_dest_table ( colA, colB, col_ref_prod_id )
        select  col1, col2 , id_col 
        from my_production_table
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying but I need id to be synced at both table. Id field is very much important because it used somewhere else to map later